# Android GridLayout of Buttons with no gaps

Tags: android, xml, button

What is the trick for removing all gaps between an GridLayout containing buttons?

I'm using XML to define the layout. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

And here is the XML:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:layoutMode="clipBounds"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"    
    android:useDefaultMargins="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="2" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button3"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="fill"
           android:layout_margin="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9" />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your xml:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ef2c6e"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#c2afdc"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="2" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="fill"
       android:layout_margin="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#d2f2f2"
       android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#c2dfa2"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#1f9fcd"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f251ff"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#a2dfaf"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#daaf2f"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f21fa2"
        android:text="9" />
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @Awais: Thanks. So the system Buttons themselves are not taking up the full space? I guess if I render my own button images there will be no gaps either.

Comment: @SparkyNZ Yes.
The padding is already given in button's 9-patch drawable in System.

Comment: @Awais: Excellent! Thanks for the hint - my custom images fit great with no gaps.. and they're 9-patch drawables too.

Comment: @SparkyNZ No problem :)
and you can add your own custom 9-patch button drawables for your layout (remember don't set gaps in drawables) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a gridview instead of gridLayout and set the properties

```
android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
```